# `transition: width 1s` on input box to increase width

Tags: css

[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sangramfuture/GS3VJ/)

using `transition: width 1s` along with `$('input').css('width', '300px');` the input box becomes 0px wide before transitioning to 300px. 
How to make transition from existing width to 300px ?

Also is there a way to make transition from right to left instead of left to right? or center static and both left and right sides increase?

html

```
<input type='text'> </input>
<button> increase width </button>
```

js

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('input').css('width', '300px');
});
```

css

```
input {
    transition: width 2s;
    left: 0px
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can do when you specify a default width to the input element:

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cfknoop/GS3VJ/2/)

```
input {
    transition: width 2s;
    width:200px; 
}
```

Comment: can we also change the direction of the increase? say from right to left?

Comment: hm, I don´t know but I think not via CSS. jQuery can do this

Comment: but then we won't use transition property i think. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: When you fixate `right` property of the input then you leave no other choice to the input than to grow to the left. (i.e. `input { position: relative; right:0; transition: width 2s; width: 200px;}` ... I did not test it though.)